# On Item Click in gridview my next activity is not showing

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-studio

I am building an app with the help of Universal Image loader library. My main activity loads images from some urls and shows it in gridview. I want to show full image in separate activity. when I clicks on any Image to open it in new activity, my application get crashed.

I am unable to understand the sample code given by UIL, its lengthy. So, I wanted to make only grid view activity.

Here is my code:

**ImageListAdapter.java**

```
 public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public String[] urls = {

            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-s-AFpvgSeew/URquc6dF-JI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Mt3xNGRUd68/s1024/Backlit%252520Cloud.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bvmif9a9YOQ/URquea3heHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/rcr6wyeQtAo/s1024/Bee%252520and%252520Flower.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n7mdm7I7FGs/URqueT_BT-I/AAAAAAAAAbs/9MYmXlmpSAo/s1024/Bonzai%252520Rock%252520Sunset.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4CN4X4t0M1k/URqufPozWzI/AAAAAAAAAbs/8wK41lg1KPs/s1024/Caterpillar.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-rrFnVC8xQEg/URqufdrLBaI/AAAAAAAAAbs/s69WYy_fl1E/s1024/Chess.jpg",

    };

    private Context context;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = convertView;

        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.single_item, null);

            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            v.setTag(vh);
        }
        else {
            vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();

        imageLoader.displayImage(urls[position], vh.imageView, options);

        return v;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java (Here Images is displaying in GridView)**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private GridView gridView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

       // listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this));



        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("id", position);
               startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

FullImageActivity.java

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageListAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(this);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)
                findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageAdapter.urls[position]));
    }

}
```

Error is not showing when I run it android studio. Please help.

Comment: Stacktrace from the crash would be awesome right about now...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the new Activity to the manifest file?

Add this

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullImageActivity "
    android:label="FullImageActivity " />
```

Comment: Yes. I have added. Still getting force closed.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use getextras()

repalace this line

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

to

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int position = i.getIntExtra("id",-1);
```

EDIT:
You are trying load image from internet, you cannot directly use image resource.

```
URL ulrn = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
InputStream iS = con.getInputStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iS);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is,

Your `FullImageActivity` Activity can not find Image Resource for imageView

From this line,

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageAdapter.urls[position]));
```

**You are trying to convert String image url in Integer so may be number format exception you are facing**.

Just load Bitmap from given Image url and try to set Bitmap to ImageView..

**pseudo code only for understanding:**

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = loadBitmapFormUrl(imageAdapter.urls[position]); // Your method which load image bitmap from given url (please use asynchronously)
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap); // After receiving image bitmap set it to imageView
```